odftoolkit - converting .odt file to PDF - page elements missing
I'm trying to save a PDF from a previously loaded .odt text document file.
this is the code:
        odt.save("C:\\Users\\maxim\\Downloads\\test.odt");
        File outFile = new File("C:\\Users\\maxim\\Downloads\\test.pdf");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( outFile );
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(odt, out, PdfOptions.create());
        out.close();

The newly saved odt file looks fine, it has a table in the middle and some text frames all over the page. The pdf file only contains the table though, with all the rest missing. Does anyone know how this could happen?

I tried several versions, also the very latest, same problem. It seems to ignore text frames, no matter if theyere anchored to the page or to the paragraph.
